# Struggling with my first solo VBA project, End if without IF - but I have an If statement

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I've been dabbling in VBA for awhile, and knowing a little bit about programing fundamentals, a little bit about best practices (make things flexible, defensive programming, trying to anticipate what will break and pre-empting it, comment every single line if you can, document properly), and a LOT of googling and determination, I've written my first program! Unfortunately, I'm encountering some errors that googling isn't getting me an answer, and so I figured I'd ask for some help. Namely, why am I getting an END IF WITHOUT IF error in my outlook checking loop, when I do have an IF? (It's triggering on the first end if). Are there any other glaring issues or problems in my code? Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

And lastly, just how badly will it break when trying to check 300k+ emails... 4 times? (I honestly couldn't think of any other method besides "Check ALL THE THINGS"

Thank you

```
 'The purpose of this macro is to automate and make easy extracting vendor  pricing from the emails they send us daily, and to automate grabbing the information
    'and turning it into a CSV file. Created by Olivier 03/10/17. In addition to the primary purpose of parsing out vendor email attachments, I was hoping to build
    'the sheet in a flexible manner so that it could easily be adapted to any file parsing situation. The excel sheet has a data range to change who we're looking
'for e-mails from, what the subject of the email is, where we want to save the attachment, what we want to call the attachment, the name and location of the data
'in the attachment, a middle pivot for putting data into our sheet, and name and locations of the parsed files once we're done grabbing the data. In addition,
'The structure of the project is designed so that someone could execute additional functions on the parsed data before saving it down again - but that's not done here.
' The steps are as follows. 1) Look in Outlook for our e-mails. 2) Download attachments. 3) Open attachments. 4) Find a particular tab. 5) Copy that tab
' 6) Get that tab as its own CSV file.



Option Explicit
'Good practices. Not having VBA guess at what a variable is.

'The numbers next to some of the variables represent which column in the Excel table it exists in, to easily call it without having to reference back to the worksheet constantly


     Dim SearchDate As Date 'Today
     'The emails are coming in daily, and we only want to be looking for stuff from today. Yesterday's is right out
     Dim SavepathAtch As String '2
     'We need to download the attachment SOMEWHERE
     Dim SearchSender As String '3
     'The person who's sending us the e-mail
     Dim SaveNameAtch As String '5
     'Now that we have a save path, we also need a file name. I could of probably combined this with SavePathAtch....
     Dim Vendor As String '1
     'Each Vendor gets their own row. I need some way of referencing them. Maybe they should be an interger, since I really only need them as 1-N
     Dim I As Integer
     'Well, I need something to make loops work...
     Dim SavePathProduct As String '9
     'We'd like to save our atachments and our final products as different files, in different spots
     Dim TabNameMid As String '7
     'The tab name that we're saving the information to as a midpoint in the process. Could have been done better by a better programmer and cutting out
     'The middle step, but I have no idea how
     Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
     'Let's have some nice shortcuts
     Dim SearchSubj As String '4
     'And we need to define who's sent us the email to look for it




  Public sFolders() As String

  Sub All()
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'Alerts would slow us down - same with the screen flickering
    Call CheckOutlook

     I = 1
     'Since we're messing with I in other parts of the code, might as well make sure it's properly reset. If this is the first time it's being used, I don't want
     'VBA to automtically assign a random integer to it. AKA apparently best practices

     If I < Range("How_Many_Vendors_Do_we_Have?") + 1 Then
     'How many vendors do we have is a COUNTA on the excel sheet to figure out, you guessed it, how many vendors we have. We need to run once for each vendor.
     ' The +1 is if we have 4 vendors, we need to run 4 times. On time to do vendor 4, we'd be at number 4, so we need I to be under 5.
     Vendor = Range("Vendor" & I)
     'Vendor1, Vendor2, Vendor3, etc. are all a named range in Excel, representing the nth cell of the first column of the datarange name ranged in Excel.
     'This is so that people can easily edit the information, and create their own rules and paths without needing to know any VBA.
     SaveNameAtch = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Vendor, Range("DataRange"), 5, 0)
     SavepathAtch = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Vendor, Range("DataRange"), 2, 0) & SaveNameAtch
     ' More stiching things together. Starting to think I really made a mistake doing it like this.
     TabNameMid = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Vendor, Range("DataRange"), 7, 0)
     'Since we've set everything up to be able to use a Vlookup to find it all, we're going to use vlookups damnit


    Call sheetcreate
    ' Get the sheets created and cleared from using the sheet yesterday or whatever.

    Call ImportData
    'One we've cleared the landing pad, the data can land.

    I = I + 1
    ' And once we've done it for one row, we need to do it for the next row! Row row row your rows


    End If
      Call SaveWorksheetsAsCsv
'Import then export each file one at a time



    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
'And now we turn alerts and screen flicking back on
  End Sub


 ''''''   GetFolderNames; ProcessFolder


  Sub CheckOutlook()
     Dim N As Long
     'For folders
     Dim X As Variant
     'For Folders
     'Dim sTemp As String
     'Shouldn't be needed
     Dim objFolder As Folder
     'More Folders
     Dim objMail As MailItem
     'The mail!
    Dim oOlAp As Object, oOlns As Object, oOlInb As Object
    Dim oOlItm As Object
Dim oOlatch As Object
' I got frustrated at things not working, and I just copy and pasted all of these in. I realize I don't need most of them to work, but I was fairly frustrated.
' I figured if I didn't use them, no harm, and where I did need to use them, they were declared how Outlook objections are usually declared.






     Call GetFolderNames
     'Acquire folders. ALL OF THEM!!

     I = 1
     'Since we're messing with I in other parts of the code, might as well make sure it's properly reset. If this is the first time it's being used, I don't want
     'VBA to automtically assign a random integer to it.


     If I < Range("How_Many_Vendors_Do_we_Have?") + 1 Then
     Vendor = Range("Vendor" & I)

     SearchSubj = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Vendor, Range("DataRange"), 4, 0)
     SearchDate = Date
     SavepathAtch = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Vendor, Range("DataRange"), 2, 0) & SaveNameAtch
     SaveNameAtch = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Vendor, Range("DataRange"), 5, 0)
     SearchSender = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Vendor, Range("DataRange"), 3, 0)
     'Really, this is just about all the same as above. Date is today, path name is where we want to save it, the numbers are where they're located in the table.

     For N = 1 To UBound(sFolders) - 1                           'loop all folders
        X = Split(sFolders(N), " || ")
       ' This is the part where I shamelessly googled until I found something working. I'm not quite sure how this is working. Kept in old comments, added my own
           Set objFolder = Session.GetFolder
           For Each objMail In objFolder.Items
           'loop every mail in the folder - check every piece of mail
              If objMail.Subject = SearchSubj Then
              'If the subject is the one we're looking for....
                 If objMail.ReceivedTime = SearchDate Then
                 'And the date is the one we're looking for....
                    If objMail.From = SearchSender Then
                    'AND  the sender is the correct sender...
                        If oOlItm.Attachments.Count <> 0 Then
                        'AND, heaven forbid, they forget to attach the email, it won't break.
                          For Each oOlatch In oOlItm.Attachments

                          oOlatch.SaveAsFile SavepathAtch
                          'SAVE ALL THE ATTACHMENTS! Don't care too much about the contents of the email
                          Exit For
                       'This Exit For is triggering an error message. I can't figure out why, and I haven't figure out how to keep debugging and ignoring the problem

                        End If
                    End If
                  End If
              End If
           Next objMail
           'Alright, we've checked this e-mail. Onto the next one

     Next N
     'Next folder
    I = I + 1
    'Ok, we've checked every single piece of mail. Wait, what do you mean we have to do it again!? I sense some horrible, horrible inefficiencies....
    ' ... but I have no idea how else I'm going to do this.
    End If

  End Sub




  Public Sub GetFolderNames()
     Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
     Dim olSession As Outlook.Namespace
     Dim olStartFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
     Dim lCountOfFound As Long
     lCountOfFound = 0
     Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
     Set olSession = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
     Set olStartFolder = olSession.PickFolder
     ReDim sFolders(1 To 1) As String
     If Not (olStartFolder Is Nothing) Then
        ProcessFolder olStartFolder
     End If
     ' Getting all of the folder names I suppose. This part took me hours and hours to try and figure out, and eventually I stumbled on someone elses code.
     ' Thank you Reddit.

  End Sub

  Sub ProcessFolder(CurrentFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder)
     Dim U As Long
     Dim olNewFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
     Dim olTempFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
     Dim olTempFolderPath As String
     Dim olCount As Long, lCountOfFound As Long
     For U = CurrentFolder.Folders.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set olTempFolder = CurrentFolder.Folders(U)
        olTempFolderPath = olTempFolder.Folderpath
        olCount = olTempFolder.Items.Count
        ReDim Preserve sFolders(1 To UBound(sFolders) + 1) As String
        sFolders(UBound(sFolders) - 1) = olTempFolderPath & " || " & CurrentFolder.EntryID
     Next
     For Each olNewFolder In CurrentFolder.Folders
        If olNewFolder.Name <> "Deleted Items" Then
           ProcessFolder olNewFolder
        End If
        'Sorting... through.. the folders? I guess?
        'Had to change the I to a U. Can't repeat variables.

     Next
  End Sub

  Sub ImportData()
' this is how we get data onto the main sheet. There probably exists a way somewhere to only save a particular tab from an attachment in an email. But until
' I know how to do that, we're going from San Fransisco to LA via Boston.
Dim PriceAttachment As Workbook
Dim PriceTab As String ' 6
Dim DataRange As String


PriceTab = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Vendor, Range("DataRange"), 6, 0)
'Defining stuff



     SaveNameAtch = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Vendor, Range("DataRange"), 5, 0)
     SavepathAtch = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Vendor, Range("DataRange"), 2, 0) & SaveNameAtch
     TabNameMid = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Vendor, Range("DataRange"), 7, 0)

'Location of the report


Workbooks.Open Filename:=SavepathAtch
'Opening up the file

Set SaveNameAtch = ActiveWorkbook
'Getting to the file

SaveNameAtch.Activate
ThisWorkbook.Sheets.TabName
'Getting to the right tab.

Cells.Select
'Selecting the new data

Selection.Copy
'Copying the new data

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(TabNameMid).Activate
'Getting back to the current sheet


Range("A1").Select
'And finding where to paste the data

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
      Application.CutCopyMode = False

  'Pasting the data

SaveNameAtch.Close SaveChanges:=False
'Close the location of the new data without changing anything




End Sub


 Sub SaveWorksheetsAsCsv()
 'AND HE MAKES THE SAVE!


Dim SaveParsedfilename As String '10
Dim SavedParsedFilePath As String '9
'Like frankenstien's monter, we're going to stich these two together

    SaveParsedfilename = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Vendor, Range("DataRange"), 10, 0)
    SavedParsedFilePath = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Vendor, Range("DataRange"), 9, 0) & SaveParsedfilename
    'EGOR! COME QUICK! IT'S ALIVE!!!

    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    'Save ALL THE SHEETS!
    If WS.Name <> "Instructions" Then
    'Except this one. We don't like this one
        WS.SaveAs SavedParsedFilePath & SaveParsedfilename, xlCSV
        'Save.exe
        End If
        'We've loaded each save onto the arc. Wait, what do you mean we forgot the dinosuars and instruction tab?
    Next

End Sub

  Sub sheetcreate()
  'This is to clear out the old data, and make sure every tab exists and is clear
  Sheets(TabName).Delete
  'Boom, headshot. Erased. Deleted. Gone.
  Set WS = Sheets.Add
  WS.Name = TabName
  'How can you kill that which has no life? Reanime all of the sheets.
  End Sub
```

Comment: Is that supposed to be in multiple files?  The *first* compile error is at `Public sFolders() As String`.  The VBE takes you to exactly the line that causes the problem, so how about narrowing down the code dump to the part that is relevant to your question.  See [mcve].

Comment: Your `For Each oOlatch In oOlItm.Attachments` is missing a `Next` - that is confusing the compiler into thinking the following `End If` doesn't have an `If`.  At this stage I will let @Mat'sMug make a shameless plug for RubberDuck, which will indent your code and also highlight these sort of issues.

Comment: @Comintern - what is wrong with `Public sFolders() As String` - doesn't that just declare a publicly scoped String array variable called `sFolders`?

Comment: @YowE3K - I'll make the shameless plug for [Rubberduck](http://www.rubberduckvba.com/) - full disclosure, I'm a contributor.  The best way to keep track of mismatched syntax like that is to use consistent indentation (the other Rubberduck features generally require code that is compilable).  Running the SmartIndenter will give *clues* that there is mismatched syntax (the `End Sub` will be misaligned), but this is a straight-up compiler job.

Comment: @YowE3K - That's my bad.  I dropped the code into a Workbook code behind, and you can't expose a public array from a class module.

Comment: @Comintern - Phew - I thought I was cracking up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to compile! There were a few errors.

First, your "If, End If" issue is due to a missing "Next" in the center of your nested "For Loops." It is in the "For Loop" where you were saving the files.

Additionally, there are issues with your Tabname vs. TabNameMid. It looks like you were going to set a variable and never did. There is a line, thisworkbook.sheets.tabname, it needs an index.  (.sheets(index) )

There are a couple of other tabname issues. You will find them after you put in the "Next."

```
       For Each oOlatch In oOlItm.Attachments
         oOlatch.SaveAsFile SavepathAtch
         'SAVE ALL THE ATTACHMENTS! Don't care too much about the contents of the email
       Next 'this is the Next that you are missing
```